# CASE with Row_Num

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, common-table-expression, sql-null

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 where for every unique PartnerNumber there are multiple ConnectorId values and multiple CommissionDate

My requirement is when I query the table in the final result I should only get rows which are having rn = 1 this was working using the below Query, but in this example P1 as per current logic it picks a row where rn = 1 but what I additionally want is if CommissionDate for rn = 1 is NULL then in that case display value of rn = 2 if not null then continue with rn = 1

**Table script:**

```
CREATE table #Final_Data
(
  CommissionDate date,
  PartnerNumber varchar(50),
  Connector_Id varchar(50),
 )

GO

insert into #Final_Data (CommissionDate,PartnerNumber,Connector_Id)
VALUES (NULL,'P1','C1'), ('2017-12-27','P1','C2')
,('2015-09-14','P2','C3'),('2011-09-13','P2','C4') 
,(NULL,'P3','C5'),(NULL,'P3','C6') 

GO
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT CommissionDate,PartnerNumber,Connector_Id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by PartnerNumber  ORDER BY CommissionDate asc) AS rn
FROM #Final_Data
)

SELECT TOP  9999999 * FROM CTE where rn = 1 
ORDER BY PartnerNumber
```

**Actual Output:**

```
CommissionDate  PartnerNumber   Connector_Id    rn
NULL                 P1              C1         1
2011-09-13           P2              C4         1
NULL                 P3              C5         1
```

**Expected output**:

```
CommissionDate  PartnerNumber   Connector_Id       rn
    2017-12-27           P1              C2         2
    2011-09-13           P2              C4         1
    NULL                 P3              C5         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional sort in the `order by` clause of the window function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY PartnerNumber  
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN CommissionDate IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CommissionDate
) AS rn
```

Answer (score 0):

GMB's answer is correct.  However, it is often more concisely expressed as:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY PartnerNumber  
    ORDER BY COALESCE(CommissionDate, '9999-01-01')
) AS rn
```

This allows the `ORDER BY` to have only one key.  And it is essentially shorthand for the SQL standard syntax:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY PartnerNumber  
    ORDER BY CommissionDate NULLS LAST
) AS rn
```

which SQL Server does not (yet???) support.